# Purpose of CINTERFACE flag in midl generated files?

Tags: c++, com, mingw, idl, midl

Using Microsoft's IDL compiler, if I do this:

```
midl a.idl /iid iid.cpp
```

I can't compile `iid.cpp` on MinGW because of the following warning:

```
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/rpcproxy.h:14:2: warning: #warning "rpcproxy type definitions require CINTERFACE" [-Wcpp]
```

But if I generate it as a C file instead, or put `-DCINTERFACE` on the `g++` command line, it compiles. What's the purpose of this flag, and why do I have to set it if I'm compiling as C++?

Answer (score 0):

By default it uses the pascal calling convention.  The mingw functions you are calling won't work with them.